Removing Lombok's `var` in an Android project
Our codebase is Android, and it targets JDK 17.
plugins {
    id("org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention") version("0.8.0")
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

There was liberal use of Lombok's val in the codebase, and some engineers decided to take it a step further and start using Lombok's var. Now we have a litany of compiler warnings to the effect of:

warning: as of release 10, 'var' is a restricted type name and cannot be used for type declarations or as the element type of an array

If we remove one of the import lombok.var; lines we instead get:
error: cannot find symbol
                var foo = bar;
                ^
symbol:   class var

It looks like the compiler warnings are not suppressable without suppressing all compiler warnings, which we don't want to do. So how do we get javac to recognize the native var?
